# what happens if i move out 5 months before the lease ends? moving out on 4/30 and lease ends on 9/30!

Tags: moving, lease

what happens if I happen to move out early 5 months before my lease ends? my lease ends on 9/30 and I move out on 4/30.. on the lease it states that if a tenant moves out early before the lease ends then the tenant has to pay prior 2 month rent including the electricity fee. so can I pay for a month rent and use  my 1 month deposit for another?

Comment: Sounds like a question for the landlord.

Comment: This will also depend on local law. Where in the world are you located?

Comment: new york city......

Answer (score 1):

The deposit is for the case that you leave the apartment in bad conditions. Therefore you cannot just assume that you will get everything back.

Talk to your landlord, let him confirm that everything is OK with the apartment (to get your deposit back) and ask him to pay your remaining rent with the deposit.

Answer (score 0):

That deposit is a security deposit to make sure you don't trash the place.

Once you inform the landlord, or their representative, using the method specified in the leasing contract that you will terminating the contract, they will schedule a time to do the inspection. They will require that all fees be settled before they do the inspection.

After the inspection they will calculate the damages, and then subtract them from the security deposit. They will refund any balance according to the method and deadline specified in the contract.

In the United States for example applicable landlord tenant law is at the state or local level. The law may specify deadlines, methods, and if you are owed any interest on the security deposit. Check with the state or city government for relevant landlord tenant laws. Many local governments have a website that will explains the relevant laws.

Generally the landlord will not assume that you will get all the security deposit back, they will require you to pay everything specified in the contract and refund back to you any remaining deposit. That avoids the situation where you damaged the place, but skipped out on some of the financial obligations, and now they have to get money from you on the last day.